# Fedora 22 DNF timeout

Tags: fedora, curl, dnf

I just installad Fedora 22 and DNF (yum's replacement) is performing terrible.

9 out of 10 request fails out of timeout, with random effect specifying IPv4 or not. The problem seems to be that DNF can't pick a proper mirror nad often pick a non-responding one, or a terribly slow one.

```
Feil: Error downloading packages:
Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=updates-released-f22&arch=x86_64 [Could not resolve host: mirrors.fedoraproject.org]
```

Also, I think IPv6 is caussing some trouble, so it has been deactivated on my system. Restarts dosn't change anything either...

Comment: Fix your Internet connection and/or your DNS servers.

Comment: Hi! My internett is good, but I'll try to update my DNS servers to googles DNS and see what happens...

Comment: Updating to googles DNS Servers worked like a charm on the first try! Thank you! If you post an answer I will accept it, also if you have tips on public DNS it would be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Couldn't resolve host name" for something well-known that should be working, is a pretty obvious indicator that something is wrong with your DNS servers. Check and change them if necessary.